# Creating the 'saveTime' function in stopwatch. Subtraction of the start date from the end date including pause

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a problem with creating the time recording function. Clicking `start` gives me the start date 'dateStart'. Clicking 'save' gives me the end date `'dateEnd' -> (this.state.dateStart + (Date.now () - this.state.timerStart))})`. `dateEnd` how to convert to date in ISOString format? An 'dateStart' subtract from `dateEnd` gives me the number that passed on the stopwatch. I must also include the stop button.

All code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-f7kkgo

Picture: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8ofLf.jpg

```
startTimer = () => {
    this.setState({
      timerOn: true,
      timerTime: this.state.timerTime,
      timerStart: Date.now() - this.state.timerTime,
      dateStart: (Date.now() - this.state.timerTime).toISOString();
    });
    this.timer = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState({
        timerTime: Date.now() - this.state.timerStart
      });
    }, 10);
  };

  stopTimer = () => {
    this.setState({ timerOn: false });
    clearInterval(this.timer);
  };

  resetTimer = () => {
    this.setState({
      timerStart: 0,
      timerTime: 0
    });
  };

  saveTimer = () => {
    this.setState({
      timerOn: false,
      dateEnd:  (this.state.dateStart + (Date.now() - 
                this.state.timerStart)).toISOString()
    }) 

    this.resetTimer();
    clearInterval(this.timer);
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use `Date.toISOString()` on a `Date` instance instead on a method of instance i.e, on `Date.now()`. I've updated the file in [CodeSandbox.](https://codesandbox.io/s/react-example-40jb0)

```
  saveTimer = () => {
    let eve=(this.state.dateStart + (this.state.dateStart  - 
                this.state.timerStart));
    let date_new=new Date(eve);
    this.setState({
      timerOn: false,
      dateEnd: date_new.toISOString()
  }) 
  console.log(this.state.dateEnd);

  this.resetTimer();
  clearInterval(this.timer);
  }
```

Comment: You didn't update file. If I stopped time and run again time between startDate and endDate is not correctly

Comment: That's not getting updated, So I am creating new one now. For your results just replace your `saveTimer()` with the above one.

Comment: If I stopped time and run again time between startDate and endDate time is not correctly

Comment: Your solution does not include stopping with the 'stop' button

Comment: It's present but hidden at start b'coz you can't stop without clock being started. Once clock is started it will be enabled. Please do check.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/196639/discussion-between-abhinav-kinagi-and-umbro).